# Python schedule events running in Backend,even if main method is stopped, python schedule library

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, server, scheduled-tasks, schedule

I created 3 files, main.py, jobA.py and jobB.py.

By using schedule library in python, created 2 schedule jobs as

1. schedule.every(60),seconds.do(run_thread,run_job_a,"jobA")
2. schedule.every(60),seconds.do(run_thread,run_job_b,"jobB")

In above,

1. run_job_x is the method in the respective file which logs the process in specific logging file.
2. 3rd parameter in string is the job name
3. And run_thread goes like below-

```
    func,name = args[0], args[1]
    thread = threading.Thread(target=func, name=name)
    if name in [thread.name for thread in threading.enumerate()]:
        logger.info(f"{name} job already running,  skipping for this instance")
        return None
    thread.start()
```

And after scheduling the events I'm running as -

```
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Now it's been 3 hrs since I executed the main.py and exited it, but the scheduled events are still running and filling up the logs.

I want to stop the scheduled events without restarting the system, how should I do it?